# Why does less +F say "can't open '+F'"?

Tags: linux, less, busybox

I just read about the advantages of using less +F over tail -f and wanted to try it out. When I do I get the following:

```
less +F /log/nginx_error.log
less: can't open '+F': No such file or directory
```

Using less without the +F option works like normal. What gives?

Comment: `less +F <filename>` works as expected for me on my Rasp Pis with Wheezy and Jessie.  Which Linux disro are you using?

Comment: Looks like the shared hosting this site is on doesn't use distro binaries so I'm getting a stripped-down version of less from BusyBox. Which I guess answers my question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the command in question on a couple Raspberry Pis, one running Wheezy, one running Jessie, and the `less +F <filename>` command worked as expected on both.

Since we determined you're using BusyBox (embedded Linux) and not a full distribution, then you probably don't have the current/full-featured LESS version that supports the `+F` flag.

Answer (score 1):

`+F` is not a typo. It's enabling the `F` command, which is “scroll forward”. From the manpage:

> If a command line option begins with +, the remainder of that option is taken to be an initial command to less.

So, your version of `less` does not support this command. I guess GNU Linux and BSD would have this command implemented – apparently your BusyBox installation does not.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like the `+F` might be a typo for `-F`. The latter is a recognized flag that, according to the manpage,

> Causes less to automatically exit if the entire  file  can  be 
>   displayed  on  the  first screen.

While I do not see the relevance of `less -F` to `tail -f`, it is at least a recognized flag. `+F`, on the other hand, is not, so it is interpreted as the filename (arguement) for the command, and as it can't find such a file, it'll come back with an error saying so.

---

PS: The above is written from a standpoint of using version 481 of less. Later versions might differ in behavior.

Comment: I don't know if +F is a typo or not but if it is there are a lot of places on the internet where it exists like that. E.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193620/is-tail-f-more-efficient-than-less-f
I tried -F instead but it said invalid option.

Comment: Here's the article that first made me aware of the +F option: http://www.brianstorti.com/stop-using-tail/